# Need help in converting and validating XMLType in Oracle SQL Table

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

So the scenario here is data is coming from an external system to oracle database.
I need to convert CLOB datatype to XMLTYPE and validate the XMLTYPE field in a table. 
If the validation or conversion fails, i need to push this record in another table. How can i achieve this.

I tried using XMLTYPE function and XMLISVALID function but i keep getting errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `WITH FUNCTION`:

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT, x CLOB);
INSERT INTO t(id, x) VALUES(1, '<root/>');
INSERT INTO t(id, x) VALUES(2, '<root></root>');
INSERT INTO t(id, x) VALUES(3, '<root><a></root>'); -- incorrect XML
```

Checking if content of column is valid XML:

```
WITH FUNCTION func(col CLOB) RETURN NUMBER
AS
  x XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
   x := XMLTYPE(col);
   RETURN 1;

   EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
   RETURN 0;
END;
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE func(x) = 1;  -- get only valid XML
-- WHERE func(x) = 0; -- get invalid XML
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=847e2a72b50700232f11ccb2c9eff56e)**

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This works well for validating XML field :)
Also can you pls help me with other query. 
I need to create a stored procedure that converts Clob field(Which has XML data)
to XMLType. If the conversion returns any error i need to insert that into error table (Which i can achieve using Exception handling i believe).